# Add LineObject to Crystal Report through Java SDK

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I have successfully connected a Crystal Report with Java in my desktop application.
Now I want to programmatically add a line to the report.

I have tried this with the following code.

```
try {
    ReportDefController rdc = reportClientDoc.getReportDefController();
} catch (ReportSDKException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PurchaseReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

Tables tables = null;
try {
    tables = reportClientDoc.getDatabase().getTables();
} catch (ReportSDKException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PurchaseReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

LineObject lineObject = new LineObject();
lineObject.clone(false);
lineObject.setSectionCode(0);
lineObject.setLineThickness(10);
lineObject.setLeft(50);
lineObject.setWidth(50);
lineObject.setHeight(10);
lineObject.setRight(20);
lineObject.setTop(10);
lineObject.setLineColor(Color.BLUE);

ReportObjectController roc = null;
try {
    roc = reportClientDoc.getReportDefController().getReportObjectController();
} catch (ReportSDKException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PurchaseReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

ReportDefController reportDefController = null;
try {
    reportDefController = reportClientDoc.getReportDefController();
    ISection section = reportDefController.getReportDefinition().getDetailArea().getSections().getSection(0);
    lineObject.setSectionName(section.getName());
    //roc.add(fieldObject, section, 0);
    if(roc.canAddReportObject(lineObject, section))
    {
        roc.add(lineObject, section, -1);
    }
} catch (ReportSDKException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PurchaseReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

This throws an error at `roc.add(lineObject, section, -1)`

How can I resolve this error and properly add the line?

Answer (score 0):

Lines and boxes are added slightly differently than regular report objects with the SDK, because they can span sections/areas.  You need to specify 'bottom' (or 'right') and 'endSection' properties, where 'bottom' is the offset from the top of the end section.  Height and width properties have no effect on these drawing objects (use 'right' combined with 'left' to specify width)

On to your problem:
First, you'll want to remove the calls to `setHeight` & `setWidth`.

Then, try something like the following code inside your last try block:

```
reportDefController = reportClientDoc.getReportDefController();
ISection section = reportDefController.getReportDefinition().getDetailArea().getSections().getSection(0);
lineObject.setSectionName(section.getName());

// BEGIN ADDED CODE

// specify section you want line to end in
lineObject.setEndSectionName(section.getName()); 

// how far down in the end section you want your line object - if you want a horizontal line, use setRight instead
lineObject.setBottom(100);                       

// specify some style so it appears (I think default is noLine)
lineObject.setLineStyle(LineStyle.singleLine);


// END ADDED CODE

if(roc.canAddReportObject(lineObject, section)) {
    roc.add(lineObject, section, -1);
}
```

This will add a small vertical line that starts at 10 (based on the setTop call in your code) and ends at 100 in the first details section.  You'll probably want to tweak the numbers and positioning to meet your needs.